# <aside> tag before or after main content

Tags: html, seo

I have the following snippet of HTML for a product list page:

```
<section>
    <aside class="pull-left">
        Sidebar
    </aside>

    <div class="pull-right">
        <article>
            Product
        </article>

        <article>
            Product
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

There is a lot of HTML before this to create the header and navigation menu

As you can see, the `<aside>` is before the main part of the content (but after stuff like the header and navbar). Will this positioning hurt SEO? Should I put the `<aside>` *after* the list of products to improve rankings, or does it not matter as semantically an `<aside>` tag is a suplemental piece of content?

Answer (score 1):

The standard practice is to place the most important parts of your page as high as possible on the HTML document. In your case, the sidebar should be placed after the product listings.
Read [this tutorial](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/link-source-ordering-seo) for more info.

Comment: The nav menu code will far outweight the sidebar. Would that make much of a difference? Does the fact that it's an `<aside>` tag mean it's demoted by search engines?